# How to match two similar but not exact sets of coordinates in python

Tags: python

I have two sets of nodes. Node set A contains a list of node ID and the node XYZ coordinates, ex: (ID: int, [x: float, y: float, z: float]). Node set B contains a node temperature and the nodes XYZ coordinates. All of the nodes in set A should (but not necessarily) be found in set B but set B can also contain additional nodes. I need to match the nodes in set A to their corresponding nodes in set B based on their coordinates. The main issue being that their coordinates are not exact matches (float errors exist).

The solution should preferably avoid non standard libraries. I have coded what I believe would not be the best solution to the problem. I've attempted to create a dict containing set B. The keys consists of a tuple containing truncated coordinates with the temperatures being the values. I then use truncated set A coordinates to query the dict.
I am wondering if there is a more elegant and accurate way of going about the problem?

Comment: You've stumbled on a distinctly non-trivial problem in computational geometry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search  Use a third-party library.

Comment: (Consider that floating point error scales with size of number and can be greater than 100 or on the order of machine ulp...  your solution will not work well for general values)

Comment: @BadZen, weighing in because your comments hit me as premature.  Wouldn't the nearest neighbor problem only apply here if the float errors are generally of an order of magnitude similar to the true distances between nodes?  Might it be true that for the OPs data, the two are actually of different magnitudes?  Another way of asking this is: Isn't it possible that after he creates an index with truncated (well, rounded) coordinates, the two sets would then match up with trivially and pose no problems or confusion as to if any two particular nodes are pairs?  Seems like his approach could work.

Comment: ...and if the two are of similar magnitude, isn't the game lost to begin with, as the data is then "corrupted" so there's no way to know which nodes are matches and which only became so due to floating point error?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably make use of [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose), it requires a bit of tuning depending on your inputs (carefully selecting `rel_tol` and `abs_tol` based on your use case).

Any many cases default values will do:

```py
import itertools
import math

def matching_temperatures(A, B):
  temperatures = dict()

  for a, b in itertools.product(A, B):
    a_id, a_xyz = a
    b_temp, b_xyz = b
    if all(math.isclose(i, j) for i, j in zip(a_xyz, b_xyz)):
      temperatures[a_id] = b_temp

  return temperatures

# Let's say our coordinates have the following error margin:
epsilon = 1e-9

A = (
  ('a', (3.3, 2.2, 1.1)), 
  ('b', (10.1, 20.2, 30.3))
)
# Same coordinates as A with a ±epsilon error: 
B = (
  ('1°c', (3.3+epsilon, 2.2-epsilon, 1.1+epsilon)), 
  ('2°c', (10.1-epsilon, 20.2+epsilon, 30.3+epsilon))
)

print(matching_temperatures(A, B))
```

In this particular example, this will print `{'a': '1°c', 'b': '2°c'}`.

But in some cases (for example your errors are greater than the default `rel_tol` of `1e-9`) then you will need to specify this: `math.isclose(i, j, rel_tol=your_epsilon)`.

Comment: Seems this could work.  I could see it taking a long time though, if you're doing a bunch of fancy (or even trivial) floating point work on every comparison.  It might be worth trying first.  But it may be that the data has to be preprocessed to be able to use equality to test all the combinations in a time-acceptable way. - all depends on the size of the data sets, of course. - I think this is the issue the OP was thinking about when talking about building new dict containing truncated values.

Comment: The complexity is O(|A|*|B|) since `isclose(a, b)` only perform a (small) constant number of operations on `(a-b)`: precisely, as the documentation states `abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)`. So unless both `A` and `B` are pretty big that shouldn't be a problem. If they both are big, then you could probably store either `A` or `B` in a structured fashion to speed up each individual nearest neighbor  request (at the cost of initialisation of you structure). Maybe a [quadtree](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Quadtree)?

Comment: I don't see how we could make use of equality tests here as we have no way of guessing a good rounding strategy in advance (unless I missed some information in the question).

Comment: Huh.  What do you think is the multiple in the "small number of operations" in `abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)` over a single CPU floating point comparison operation?  Just the multiplication probably takes a few times the number of CPU cycles.  I'm guessing 10x conservatively.  And "rounding strategy"?  That's the same exact problem as picking a proper tolerance in your solution, but it's applied to each value only once.

Comment: ...oh wait.  The map's hash algorithm turns the floating point comparison into an integer comparison.  Even faster. I bet the comparison difference is 50x.

Comment: To be fair, @cglacet, I missed your statement "So unless both A and B are pretty big".  Sure.  If we're not talking about a lot of data, then your solution is probably fine, along with any other solution that produces the right answer.  We don't know how big the OPs data set is, and it's much more interesting, if not rewarding, if we care about our code being fast, IMO.

Comment: I said "a good rounding strategy", but I meant "a rounding strategy" as I don't really see how this can be done. Unless the coordinates are supposed to be aligned on some discrete coordinate system that is known in advance. Since the OP makes no reference of this, I make no such assumption. Why couldn't rounding work? For example, suppose that the maximum error is `< 0.05` and you decide to round to the closest 0.1 value, both `3.09` and `3.11` will be rounded to `3.1` so far so good, but if you round `3.049` and `3.051` then they will be rounded to `3` and `3.1` which may lead to an error.

Comment: If writing an optimized version is easy, then why not doing it. But if this is not obvious, then I prefer to write a simple (not optimized version) that works right now. If this is too slow, then I would just switch to numpy. If it's still too slow, then I would consider thinking about an optimization. If you feel like your solution is viable and faster why don't you just answer the question? I mean, stackoverflow is not a place where everything stops as soon as one answer as been given. On the other hand it's hard to compare two algorithms when only one exists.

Comment: It all depends on the data.  In most real-world cases, one knows their data very well.  It wouldn't be surprising if any two coordinates in the OPs data differed by at least 100.  Like maybe they're taken from major cities around the world.  Maybe they're taken on an even grid.  Who knows.  But say we knew that they were always at least a few miles apart, and we rounded to feet.  We'd be fine.  So if the data is in feet, we could just round to whole integers.  It usually isn't a problem picking the right way to sculpt your data appropriately.

Comment: My answer to the question is "what the OP was thinking is better than your solution". That helps him tremendously. - I am comparing algorithms.  I'm comparing yours against his. - I could code this thing in my sleep.  It's more fun to do this. - the OP was already on the right track. I think he's better served by following his own ideas, as I said in my comments to his question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191945/discussion-between-cglacet-and-steve).

Comment: I would add to your chat but I dont have enough rep points. As a sample point I have (183822,  [4.933644186198 ,  2.929687842E-06, 0.0]) and (42300, [4.933644186198 ,  2.929687859E-06, 0.0]) which are equivalent points. I'm looking at upward of 100k nodes per set.